# woocommerce allow users to select or use avatar

Tags: comments, woocommerce-offtopic, avatar

I am working on constructing a ecommerce site that is run by woocommerce and the free woo theme artificer.  Standard with the plugins there is a my account page which allows you to put in basic information.  The users can also use their accounts to comment on blog posts.  When they comment they currently have the default grey siloutte for their associated image.  How do I allow them to associate an avatar with their account and use that when they comment?

The testing is going on at the address:
[www.violet-rain.com/post-trees](http://www.violet-rain.com/post-trees/)

Answer (score 1):

Your page seems to be currently using gravatars for comments, which is typical WP mechanics. Users with gravatar accounts will have their gravatars show up.

WordPress doesn't natively provide "local" (specific to the site) avatars. You will need to use a third party plugin/solution if you want that.

Comment: How would the site know that a user had a gravatar account?  I dont see anywhere to set their link or anything like that, but am not very familiar with gravatars.

Comment: @tech WP generates special image link to gravatar (with hash of user's email, you can see those links in page source). If the hash is recognized gravatar serves avatar image, otherwise it's redirected to fallback image.

Comment: Are you familiar with any plugins that allow the use of gravatar and if they do not have a gravatar they can upload an image just for your site?  Or is that not even possible?

Comment: @tech There probably is something like around, I hadn't used anything like that in practice myself. Please note that plugin recommendations are considered [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

I think all your needs would be solved with this:

[Plugin github Repository](https://github.com/bangbay/wp-user-avatar)